# The dotnet dbcontext Scaffold ef and scaffold-dbcontext command does not find the package

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to generate my models from the database using Entity framework via reverse engineering. but the command does not work.
Here is the exact command I entered

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold  "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=DiceDatatable; " Microsoft.EntyFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models
```

it gives me the following error:
[Scaffol error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jes1q.png)

```
Unable to find provider assembly 'Microsoft.EntyFrameworkCore.SqlServer'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project.
```

I don't understand what is happening because I installed everything as you can see in the image above

I specify that all the old and new project generates the same error.

the problem occurs after i updated visual studio 2022 from preview to current version.
I am also moving from sql server 2016 to sql server 2022

Environmental Information

EF Core version: 6.4
Database provider:  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Target framework: NET 6.0
Operating system: windows 11
IDE:  Visual Studio 2022 17.1.4

Comment: Did you install the nuget package Microsoft.EntyFrameworkCore.SqlServer?

Comment: Please share your .csproj

Comment: Yes. Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer is successfully installed